Why does the document keep the original data when I update it? It is returned into the previous status right away. No error
I have a collection with a lot of documents in Firestore Database. I wrote a function to update the data of a document in React.
try {

    await firebase.app
        .firestore()
        .collection("Records")
        .doc(recordId)
        .update({ public: value, _author: UserProfile.getEmail() });
           
    return {
        status: status.SUCCESS
    }

} catch(error) {
    return {
        status: status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    }
}

I am updating the document as an authenticated user, and for other documents, the update function works correctly. But it doen't work only for a few records.
I checked the permission of the user in Authentication of Firebase. Everything was enabled there.
Here is an example of the document.


"it doen't work only for a few records"... what does it do instead? How exactly does it not work?

Your question should contain the exact steps that anyone can take to reliably reproduce the problem.  This means you should show at least one of the documents where the update doesn't work, and explain what actually happens that's different than what you expect.  Also keep in mind that we can't see the return value of UserProfile.getEmail(), nor can we see the value of recordId, so we can't fully see what this code does in practice.

I just posted the format of one document.

I have experienced the issue before. I am sure that it is a permission issue. You can add "Access" field into the document.
The "Access" field consists of "Edit", "Exec", "Owner", "Read", etc.
"Access": {
    "Exec": ["test@email.com"],
    "Owner": ["test@email.com"],
    ...
}

When I add the user's email into "Owner" array, it worked.

What is this in reference to? The contents of a Cloud Firestore document have no bearing on permissions

Yes, that's correct. When I add my email, "test@fbc.ru" into "Owner" list, it works. Thank you!

Something very fishy going on here. This answer was posted before OP added the second screenshot showing the document structure

I just posted the answer with my experience from an ongoing project which I am working. Last month, I got same issue.
